Setting up YSocketIo with Tiptap Nextjs and hocuspocus/server
I am trying to set up YSocketIo with Nextjs Tiptap and hocuspocus/server. Everything works, until I want to add socket routes and I get nothing back. I don't even get "User connected..." when connecting although the collaboration works and there are no errors. What is happening to my logs?
Server code:
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "@hocuspocus/server";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server as SocketServer } from "socket.io";
import { YSocketIO } from 'y-socket.io/dist/server'

const host = "localhost"
const port = "1234"

const app = express();

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new SocketServer(httpServer);

const collaborationServer = Server.configure({
  onConnect: (context) => {
    console.log("User connected", context.user);
  }
});

const ysocketio = new YSocketIO(io)
ysocketio.initialize()

// Listen for Socket.IO connections
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Socket.IO connection established");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Socket.IO connection disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("test", () => {
    console.log("test");
  });

  collaborationServer.handleConnection(socket, null, context);
});


httpServer.listen(port, host, undefined, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))

Nextjs Page:
import Collaboration from "@tiptap/extension-collaboration";

import StarterKit from "@tiptap/starter-kit";
import { EditorContent, useEditor } from "@tiptap/react";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { HocuspocusProvider } from "@hocuspocus/provider";
import CollaborationCursor from "@tiptap/extension-collaboration-cursor";
import Paragraph from "@tiptap/extension-paragraph";

import Document from "@tiptap/extension-document";
import Placeholder from "@tiptap/extension-placeholder";
import Text from "@tiptap/extension-text";
import * as Y from "yjs";


import { SocketIOProvider } from 'y-socket.io';

const doc = new Y.Doc()
const provider = new SocketIOProvider('http://localhost:1234', 'room-name', doc, {
    autoConnect: true,
    resyncInterval: 5000,
    disableBc: false
});


const TipTapEditor = () => {

    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [
            StarterKit.configure({
                history: false,
            }),
            // Register the document with Tiptap
            Collaboration.configure({
                document: doc,
                
            }),
            CollaborationCursor.configure({
                provider,
                user: {
                    name: "Cyndi",
                    color: "#f783ac",
                },
            }),
            Placeholder.configure({
                placeholder:
                    "Write something … Itll be shared with everyone else looking at this example.",
            }),
        ],
    });

    const handleEmit = () => {
        console.log('emitting test');

        provider.emit('test', []);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleEmit}>
                Test Emit
            </button>
            <EditorContent editor={editor} />
        </>
        
    );
};

export default TipTapEditor;


I found a way by just having an socket on the side and making the y-socketio handle the documents, and skiping the hocuspocus/sever
Nextjs Code:
import Collaboration from "@tiptap/extension-collaboration";

import StarterKit from "@tiptap/starter-kit";
import { EditorContent, useEditor } from "@tiptap/react";
import React from "react";
import CollaborationCursor from "@tiptap/extension-collaboration-cursor";

import Placeholder from "@tiptap/extension-placeholder";
import * as Y from "yjs";


import { SocketIOProvider } from 'y-socket.io';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io('ws://localhost:1234');
const doc = new Y.Doc()
const provider = new SocketIOProvider('ws://localhost:1234', 'room-name', doc, {
    autoConnect: false,
    resyncInterval: 5000,
    disableBc: false
})

const TipTapEditor = () => {

    provider.connect();

    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [
            StarterKit.configure({
                history: false
            }),
            Collaboration.configure({
                document: doc
            }),
            CollaborationCursor.configure({
                provider,
                user: {
                    name: "Cyndi",
                    color: "#f783ac",
                },
            }),
        ],
    });

    const handleEmit = () => {
        console.log('emitting test');

        socket.emit('test', 'test');
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleEmit}>
                Test
            </button>
            <EditorContent editor={editor} />
        </>
        
    );
};

export default TipTapEditor;

Server Code:
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server as SocketServer } from "socket.io";
import { YSocketIO } from 'y-socket.io/dist/server'

const host = "localhost"
const port = "1234"

const app = express();

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new SocketServer(httpServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

const ysocketio = new YSocketIO(io)

ysocketio.initialize()

// Listen for Socket.IO connections
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Socket.IO connection established");
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Socket.IO connection disconnected");
  });


});


httpServer.listen(port, host, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))

